# update: problem showing image while waiting to page to load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to show an image to let the user known that something is happening while some pages are being loaded.

I tried several examples that I found in google.
My goal is every time that I click in some link, the image should appear to let me known that the page is loading. But I'm not able to do that.

So far what I accomplish is that the image appear when I load that page and don't disappear, but I would like to make this available when I click on a link.

What I've done:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#loading").hide();
});
</script>

<img id="loading" alt="" src="/ajax-loader.gif"/>

#loading {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 position: fixed;
 display: block;
 opacity: 0.7;
 background-color: #fff;
 z-index: 99;
 text-align: center;
}

#loading-image {
 position: absolute;
 top: 100px;
 left: 240px;
 z-index: 100;
}
```

Any help is appreciate :)
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will be of some help:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar

Comment: I had already saw that one but it's static. I would like something that would progress along time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple one: http://www.webappers.com/progressBar/

That's the first result in google when I type in "js progress bar" -- there's hundreds of others.